# Go back to absolute positioning when scrolling up after changing to fixed position when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a page that has a small navigation box on the left that I would like to be always visible as the user scrolls down. I'm using the below script to get that effect and it is working great except for one problem.

When I scroll back up the box does not revert back to its absolute position but keeps the fixed position which then overlaps the beginning banner. I'm new to this idea, any ideas or suggestions on how to make the div go back to it's original settings when the user scrolls up to that point?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 229){ //looking for the window to scroll to 229px in this example
     $('.timeline').css({position:'fixed',margin:'-250px 0 0 50px'});
} else {
     $('.timeline').css({position:'absolute'});
    }
});
```

To see the page I am working on: http://embassyofrock.com/press

Comment: It is going back to absolute.  Your margin is staying though.  Set your margin back to `0 0 0 50px`

Comment: Wow you are are right, I can't believe I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not unsetting the margin when you revert back to absolute. I would suggest adding/removing a class instead so you don't need to worry about resetting values.

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 229){
        $('.timeline').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.timeline').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    margin: -250px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```